# Compile Time Error In Core Java

Tags: java

//Why is this showing a compile-time error when I call hello method?

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String [] args) {

            System.out.println(hello());
   }

 public static void hello() {

          System.out.println("from hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the error message can give some clues.

Answer (score 2):

Because `hello()` doesn't return a `String`, `Object` or any of the other types accepted by the various `println` methods defined in [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

In fact, you could pass any type of parameter to `println` and get some form of output, but since the return type of your method is declared as `void`, you're not actually passing a parameter.

You can get rid of the error by changing the `hello()` method to something like, for example:

```
public static String hello() {
    return "Hello world";
}
```

Or by changing your method invocation to:

```
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `hello()` doesn't return anything.

Try something like this:

```
public class Test 
{
  public static void main(String [] args) 
  {
      System.out.println(hello());
  }

  public static String hello() 
  {
      return "Hi!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Method hello must return an value. See follow code snippet:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(hello()); //this method must return value
    }

    public static String hello() {
        return "Hello Baghi!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your hello method did not return any value/object (anything **printable** by `println()` ).

You can change your method as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(hello());
}
public static String hello() 
{
    return ("from hello");
}
```

**Alternatively**, change the way you **call** the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    hello();
}
public static void hello() 
{
   System.out.println("from hello");
}
```